# Commands that do not introduce indentation or extra vertical space

Tags: alignment

Want to write a letter with the article class.  With `expl3` commands for displaying Name, Role and Address without having any indentation or the extra spacing between them.

The current implementation introduces extra spacing between Name, Role and Address, which I do not want.

The result will look like this

```
                                                    Heime Borgia
                                                    Developer
                                                    Plateau de Moulon
                                                    3 rue Joliot-Curie

Gon Cholden
Developer
Plateau de Moulon
3 rue Joliot-Curie

Feodor Svertlov
Developer
Plateau de Moulon
3 rue Joliot-Curie
```

I also want to handle a Letter Title that has nothing to do with the document title. And with the capability to write multiple letters within the same document.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}

\setlength {\parindent} {0pt}  % Remove paragraph indent

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand {\WriteName} { O{left} m }
  {
    \str_case:nn { #1 }
      {
        {left}  { \begin{flushleft} #2 \end{flushleft} }
        {right} { \begin{flushright} #2 \end{flushright} }
      }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand {\WriteRole} { O{left} m }
  {
    \str_case:nn { #1 }
      {
        {left}  { \begin{flushleft} #2 \end{flushleft} }
        {right} { \begin{flushright} #2 \end{flushright} }
      }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand {\WriteAddress} { O{left} m }
  {
    \str_case:nn { #1 }
      {
        {left}  { \begin{flushleft} #2 \end{flushleft} }
        {right} { \begin{flushright} #2 \end{flushright} }
      }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

%% ENGLISH

\selectlanguage{english}
\hspace*{0.5\linewidth}

\WriteName [right] {Heime Borgia}
\WriteRole {Developer}
\WriteAddress {Plateau de Moulon \\ 3 rue Joliot-Curie}

\WriteName {Gon Cholden}
\WriteRole {Developer}
\WriteAddress {Plateau de Moulon \\ 3 rue Joliot-Curie}

\WriteName {Feodor Svertlov}
\WriteRole {Developer}
\WriteAddress {Plateau de Moulon \\ 3 rue Joliot-Curie}

January 2023 (date)

The Deterioration of Health and safety (title)

GNU is an operating system that is free software—that is, it respects
users' freedom. The GNU operating system consists of GNU packages
(programs specifically released by the GNU Project) as well as free
software released by third parties. The development of GNU made it
possible to use a computer without software that would trample your
freedom.

%% ITALIAN

\newpage
\selectlanguage{italian}
\hspace*{0.5\linewidth}

\WriteName [right] {Heime Borgia}
\WriteRole {Developer}
\WriteAddress {Plateau de Moulon \\ 3 rue Joliot-Curie}

\WriteName {Gon Cholden}
\WriteRole {Developer}
\WriteAddress {Plateau de Moulon \\ 3 rue Joliot-Curie}

\WriteName {Feodor Svertlov}
\WriteRole {Developer}
\WriteAddress {Plateau de Moulon \\ 3 rue Joliot-Curie}

January 2023 (date)

Il Deterioramento della Salute e della Sicurezza (Title)

GNU è un sistema operativo che è software libero, ovvero rispetta
libertà degli utenti. Il sistema operativo GNU è costituito da pacchetti
GNU (programmi rilasciati appositamente dal Progetto GNU) e gratuiti
software rilasciato da terze parti. Lo sviluppo di GNU ce l'ha fatta
possibile utilizzare un computer senza software che possa calpestare il
tuo libertà

\end{document}
```

Comment: >"In particular I would like to write expl3 based commands"  Then show us some of the expl3 code that you have tried to work out. (FYI, I did not downvote your question.)

Comment: Don't use `flushleft` or `flushright` environments, as they introduce extra vertical space.  Try using `{\raggedright #1 \par}` instead.

Comment: I need left alignment when doing `\WriteName`, `\WriteRole`, `\WriteAddress` after each other.  And be able to shift the whole thing on the right side of the page.

Comment: I don't understand what would be the problem. You can use `\raggedleft` or `\raggedright` and the grouping to limit the scope of its effects.

Comment: Have added an example.  Want to put the text to the right or left sides of the page, with the text having left alignment.

Comment: Then use a parbox to contain #1 and the aforementioned ragged commands outside the parbox to flush it to the left or right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you're using is wrong: every `flushright` or `flushleft` environment adds vertical space before and after it (ensuring that the spaces don't cumulate).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showframe} % to show the text block margins

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { ragonese/address }
 {
  name    .tl_set:N = \l_ragonese_address_name_tl,
  role    .tl_set:N = \l_ragonese_address_role_tl,
  place   .tl_set:N = \l_ragonese_address_place_tl,
  address .tl_set:N = \l_ragonese_address_address_tl,
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\sender}{m}
 {
  \begin{flushright} % opens a group
  \ragonese_address_print:n { #1 }
  \end{flushright}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\addressee}{m}
 {
  \begin{flushleft} % opens a group
  \ragonese_address_print:n { #1 }
  \end{flushleft}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \ragonese_address_print:n
 {
  \keys_set:nn { ragonese/address } { #1 }
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  \tl_use:N \l_ragonese_address_name_tl \\
  \tl_if_blank:VF \l_ragonese_address_role_tl { \tl_use:N \l_ragonese_address_role_tl \\ }
  \tl_use:N \l_ragonese_address_place_tl \\
  \tl_use:N \l_ragonese_address_address_tl
  \end{tabular}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\sender{
  name=Heime Borgia,
  role=Developer,
  place=Plateau de Moulon,
  address=3 rue Joliot-Curie
}

\addressee{
  name=Gon Cholden,
  role=Developer,
  place=Plateau de Moulon,
  address=3 rue Joliot-Curie
}

\addressee{
  name=Feodor Svertlov,
  place=Plateau de Moulon,
  address=3 rue Joliot-Curie
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like the idea of defining keys.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is close to what you are looking for.  The main change was the addition of a `\parbox` and increasing `\parskip`.  Blank lines are used to start new paragraphs (or `\par`).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Remove paragraph indent
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

%% ENGLISH

\selectlanguage{english}
\hspace*{0.5\linewidth}\parbox{0.5\textwidth}{%
Heime Borgia (sender)\\
Developer (role)\\
3 rue Joliot-Curie (address)}

Gon Cholden (receiver)\\
Developer (role)\\
3 rue Joliot-Curie (address)

Gon Cholden (receiver)\\
Developer (role)\\
3 rue Joliot-Curie (address)

\hspace*{0.5\linewidth}January 2023 (date)

{\centering\large The Deterioration of Health and safety (title)\par}% \textbf might look good here

GNU is an operating system that is free software—that is, it respects
users' freedom. The GNU operating system consists of GNU packages
(programs specifically released by the GNU Project) as well as free
software released by third parties. The development of GNU made it
possible to use a computer without software that would trample your
freedom.

%% ITALIAN

\newpage
\selectlanguage{italian}
\hspace*{0.5\linewidth}\parbox{0.5\textwidth}{%
Heime Borgia (sender)\\
Developer (role)\\
3 rue Joliot-Curie (address)}

Gon Cholden (reciever)\\
Developer (role)\\
3 rue Joliot-Curie (address)

Gon Cholden (reciever)\\
Developer (role)\\
3 rue Joliot-Curie (address)

\hspace*{0.5\linewidth}January 2023 (date)

\vskip 2\parskip
\centerline{\large Il Deterioramento della Salute e della Sicurezza (Title)}

GNU è un sistema operativo che è software libero, ovvero rispetta
libertà degli utenti. Il sistema operativo GNU è costituito da pacchetti
GNU (programmi rilasciati appositamente dal Progetto GNU) e gratuiti
software rilasciato da terze parti. Lo sviluppo di GNU ce l'ha fatta
possibile utilizzare un computer senza software che possa calpestare il
tuo libertà

\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I made a title stand out in size ?

Comment: For what purpose do you do `\parbox`.

Comment: If uses a common indentation.  You could also use `\leftskip` or \hangindent`, but I've always been fond of `\parbox`s.

Comment: Would I then use some horizontal space followed by a parbox ?

Comment: `\vskip 2\parskip` gets 2 to be displayed

Comment: Not when I run it.  Try `\vspace{2\baselineskip}`, or just remove the 2.  Note that the first page uses a different approach.